# I'm having an issue with my game in TkInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm making a game where there is a random number and you have to guess the number while all displayed on an interface. The code was working without the interface (this is the "guess" function) but as soon as I tried to move it into the function when the button is pressed, the game always freezes.

Could someone help me find the problem?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


root = Tk()

root.title("Mack's totally advanced Number Guesser!")
root.geometry('404x300')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg='black')



fontA = 'BigNoodleTitling'
fontSizeA = 20

num = random.randint(1, 100)

# The issue is below

def guess():
    correctGuess = False
    while (correctGuess == False):
        guess = guessEnt.get()
        guess = int(guess)
        if (guess == num):
            correctGuess = True
            welcomeLbl.config(text="Correct! Congratulations...")
        elif (guess > num):
            welcomeLbl.config(text='Err, TOO HIGH. Try Again.')
        elif (guess < num):
            welcomeLbl.config(text='Errrrrr, TOO LOW. Try Again.')



def start():
    instrButton.grid_forget()
    startButton.grid_forget()
    welcomeLbl.config(text="Guess The Number! (1-100)")
    welcomeLbl.grid(pady=30)
    guessEnt.grid(row=3, column=0)
    guessButton.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=20)



def instructions():
    instrButton.grid_forget()
    startButton.grid_forget()
    welcomeLbl.config(text="So you need instructions ay?")
    welcomeLbl.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    welcomeLbl.config(text="Well, it's quite simple")
    welcomeLbl.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    welcomeLbl.config(text="Just guess the number!")
    welcomeLbl.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    welcomeLbl.config(text="How you say?")
    welcomeLbl.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    welcomeLbl.config(text="Type your guess into the box!")
    welcomeLbl.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    welcomeLbl.config(text="Welcome Random Person")
    instrButton.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=N)
    startButton.grid(row=4,column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=E+W, pady=25)




titleLbl = Label(root)
titleLbl['borderwidth'] = (2)
titleLbl['relief'] = ('solid')
titleLbl['text'] = ("Mack's totally advanced Number Guessing Game!")
titleLbl['font'] = (fontA, fontSizeA)
titleLbl.grid(row=0, column=0)


welcomeLbl = Label(root, fg='white', bg='black')
welcomeLbl['text'] = ("Welcome Random Person")
welcomeLbl['font'] = (fontA, 30)
welcomeLbl.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)

instrButton = Button(root, command=instructions)
instrButton['text'] = ("Instructions")
instrButton['font'] = (fontA, fontSizeA)
instrButton.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=N)

startButton = Button(root, fg='red', command=start)
startButton['text'] = ("Start")
startButton['font'] = (fontA, 40)
startButton.grid(row=4,column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=E+W, pady=25)

guessEnt = Entry(root)
guessEnt['font'] = (fontA, fontSizeA)

guessButton = Button(root, command=guess)
guessButton['text'] = ("Guess")
guessButton['font'] = (fontA, 20)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks, 
Mack.

Comment: Just remove the line `while (correctGuess == False)` .

Comment: Thankyou @jizhihaoSAMA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `while (correctGuess == False):`. If the answer is incorrect, it will drop into an infinite loop since `correctGuess` doesn't change in the loop -- it's always `False`. You can add `print(1)` in the loop -- you'll see that it can't exit. Remove that line and it should be fine.

Comment: You should also remove the ``CorrectGuess``'s 2 lines -- they're doing nothing.